# Ajax validation, different Messages

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi guys I have a real problem with my validation in JSF. I want to validate a Mail-Address if it's already used and the correct mail format. Here are the picture how it should look.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bs9nshmuurauc2e/Unbenannt.JPG
I hope can understand the problem. I don't now how I can implement it.
Can I set different messages for different events?

I use primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.1

```
<p:row>
    <p:column style="width:400px">
        <h:outputLabel for="email" styleClass="outputRight" value="#{msg['regi_mail']}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:350px">
        <p:inputText style="width:350px" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_mail_valid']}" validatorMessage="#{msg['regi_mail_valid']}" id="email" value="#{regiBean.user.EMAIL}" required="true">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="format user" />

        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:410px">
        <h:panelGroup id="mail" class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x" />
        <p:overlayPanel for="mail" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:panel>
                TEXTTEXTTEXT
            </p:panel>
        </p:overlayPanel>
        <p:message id="format" for="email" />
    </p:column>
</p:row>

<p:row>
    <p:column style="width:400px">
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="outputRight" value="Username" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:350px">
        <h:outputLabel id="user" style="color: green;" value="#{regiBean.user.EMAIL}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:panelGroup id="us" class="fa fa-minus-square fa-2x" />
        <h:panelGroup/>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this but front end only different.

1. XHTML File

[image: Front-end xhtml file]

1. The Bean Code

[image: Setter and getter]

[image: validateEmail Method]

[image: Email Format and Email Present or Not in ur DB]

**I hope you will get some help from this.**

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, I see the question was asked in Feb already. However, seems this would be a case where you should rather supply a custom validator. Here is my suggestion:

1. Remove the `validatorMessage` attribute from you `id="email"` element. Also remove the `f:validateRegex` validator in that input element.
2. Create a custom validator. It should:

   - Have a `@ManagedBean` (or similar) annotation (so that the EL in your JSF page can reference it)
   - implement `javax.faces.validator.Validator`
   - override the `validate()` method. In it you do your validations, e.g. check your regexp as well as query the database for existing addresses via e.g. JPA (or an EJB business method). If validation fails, you throw a `javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException`, that is constructed with a `javax.faces.application.FacesMessage` instance containing the relevant error message (there are various constructors, find an applicable one).
   - If you do not want to code something in this validator, but "pass it in" from the JSF page, you could do that via attribute passing. Useful if you e.g. would want to pass in your (i18z'ed) error message, values of other fields on the form, etc. etc. The only things available inside the `validate()` method by default is the FacesContext, the UIComponent, and the value that is validated. (See example below.)
3. Modify your JSF similar to the example below.

Example - Validator class:

```
@ManagedBean public class MyEmailValidator implements Validator {
    @EJB UserEJBLocal userEJB; // supposing you want to use a method in there to get list of e-mail addresses
    private static final String REGEXP = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    @Override public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (! Pattern.matches(REGEXP, value.toString())) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(component.getAttributes().get("formatMsg")));
        }
        List existingAddresses = userEJB.getAllAddresses(); // or whatever method your are using to obtain current addresses, e.g. JPA.
        if (existingAddresses.contains(value.toString()) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "The address already exists." // could also be passed in as attribute, etc.
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

Example - JSF snippet:

```
<p:inputText id="email" value="#{regiBean.user.EMAIL}"
       requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_mail_valid']}" required="true"
>
   <f:validator binding="${myEmailValidator}" />
   <f:attribute name="formatMsg" value="#{msg['regi_mail_valid']}" />
   : <!-- other attributes, if needed -->
   <f:ajax event="blur" render="email-msg user" />
</p:inputText>
:
<p:message id="email-msg" for="email" />
```

Well, the above example may not be complete, but might point you in the right direction.

OK, so maybe you want to check the current row's e-mail against the e-mails in the other rows? You are a bit out of luck... The only way I can think of is to somehow gather them all into a list, which you can pass via another attribute to the validator. Not very easy with a dynamic table... You might want to rethink your process.